# gulp для верстки. Использование сервера

Tags: вёрстка, gulp

Впервые решил использовать gulp. Посмотрел видео, все работает, однако возникают вопросы, как удобней и правильней поступать:

1. Можно ли как-то открывать собранные страницы через сервер?. т.е. можно конечно проставлять ссылки в верстке, или копировать название страницы и вставлять после адреса сервера, но есть ли более простой способ?
2. Для разбиения/сборки js следует использовать webpack?

Comment: Испробовал все плагины для компиляции PUG для vscode. И все отвратительно нелепы. Так что вопрос про gulp актуален

Comment: обидно, что придется использовать все эти сложности gulp, хотя почти весь функционал уже встроен( но, при этом, вот сейчас у меня сложный сайт из кучи страниц и нескольких шаблонов. pug был бы мне невероятно полезен. я бы и js разбил на модули

Comment: и давай старую переписку удалим